# Error on packstack install (Puppet)

Tags: openstack

Installing packstack on the controller using:
`packstack --answer-file=/root/newton-answer.txt`

Results in the following error:

> Error appeared during Puppet run controller

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oENUV.png

Comment: Hi Kishan, can you share the full journal logs please?

Comment: Its really hard to tell whats wrong. Can you please provide some other information as well.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oENUV.png